# Vim keeps unindenting

Tags: vim, indentation

Vim keeps unindenting the lines I want to keep indented if I don't write anything on them... I'll give an example, where the | is the caret.

1. Caret is indented and I press enter

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")
       |
   ```
2. Caret is indented on the next line, and now I press the up arrow

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")

       |
   ```
3. Now the caret isn't indented anymore, what happened?

   ```
   if expression:
       print("hello world")
   |
   ```

So how do I keep the indent?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Vi and Vim.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Same question on Vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/how-do-i-prevent-vim-from-unindenting-empty-lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, Vim intentionally removes indent of empty lines if the indent was added automatically. But, this does *not* happen if you have inserted any text on the line, even if you delete it. So on a case-by-case basis, just insert some text and delete it with backspace if you want to keep the indent of an empty line. A mapping also works, if you *always* want to keep it:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR>x<BS>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the expected behavior of vim . Since you have skipped the next line it assume you do not want to write in that particular block of code

Comment: Well then, I don't want the "expected" behavior of Vim, how can I make it so it doesn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

On my installation, it keeps the indentation (for C file at least).

You should try to insert a new line using o in normal mode.

Then according the the documentation (see `:help o`):

> When 'autoindent' is on, the indent for a new line is obtained from
>   the previous line. When 'smartindent' or 'cindent' is on, the indent
>   for a line is automatically adjusted for C programs.

You are probably using only the 'autoindent' option.

See `:help indenting` for more information.

For non C-like language, you might need to rely on the $VIMRUNTIME/indent files.

You can enable it by adding `:set filetype indent on` assuming your language is supported. Otherwise, you will have to write your own indent file.